# Saving Numpy array into a binary file and reading it properly

Tags: python, numpy

As the snippet below illustrates, I am writing a bunch of Numpy arrays with shapes (3, 225, 400) into a binary file sequentially.

```
with open("frames", "wb") as f:
    while ...: 
        screen_buffer.tofile(f)
```

And I'd like to verify whether I am able to write those arrays correctly or not. However, I have trouble while printing the binary file.

```
with open("frames", "rb") as f:
    x = np.fromfile(fr, dtype=np.uint8)
    while len(x)>0:
        print(x)
        x = np.fromfile(fr, dtype=np.uint8)
```

The code above prints only a single row:

```
[31 55 55 ... 103 103 103]
```

instead of this:

[image: one complete buffer]

Comment: The `tofile/fromfile` combination does not save `shape` or `dtype`.  Use the `save/load` pair instead.

Comment: I cannot use save/load because "save" writes one array into one file. Considering my code produces thousands of arrays in a loop, this approach leads me to create thousands of separate binary files.

Comment: `save` writes a header plus data.  `tofile` just writes the data. Your choice. Do you understand how arrays are stored in memory?  Things like shape, dtype, and databuffer?